# Prevent hover state to be dismissed in Firefox DevTools

Tags: html, debugging, firefox, hover, firefox-developer-tools

I want the hover state of an element to be persistent when clicking on another element, but the Firefox DevTools remove the hover state.

See the following GIF:
[image: Firebug Hover]

Is there any solution for this?
In Chrome the hover state is not removed, therefore this behavior confuses me.

Comment: Your GIF shows the [Firefox DevTools](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/), not Firebug. You should update your question accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately there's no solution for this as of now. [A bug has already been reported for this issue though](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=985517).

Answer (score 0):

There's currently (Firefox 52.0a1) no way to persistently show the highlighting of an element within the Firefox DevTools.

Though there is a feature request asking for this in [bug 959073](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=959073).

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question, Muarl asks about the pseudo-class lock, not highlighting elements.

Comment: Hmm, I guess you're right. @Muarl, maybe pbrosset's answer is more correct than my one. I was referring to the box model highlighting within the website when hovering an element within the *Inspector* panel of the DevTools.

Comment: Yeah, correctly, the lock of the hover state. I will update the correct answer.